# Refactor JS method with multiple optional arguments

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a function that receives two arguments that I want them to be optional (the last two):

```js
const renderDate = (date, locale, format) => {
  if (locale === undefined) { locale = 'en' }
  if (format === undefined) { format = 'D MMM' }
  if (locale === 'de' && format === 'D MMM') {
    const indexD = format.lastIndexOf('D')
    format = `${format.slice(0, indexD + 1)}o${format.slice(indexD + 1, format.length)}`
  }

  moment.locale(locale)
  return moment(date).format(format)
}

console.log(renderDate('2019-09-04', 'Do MMM'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

I can't do something like this:

```
const renderDate = (date, locale = 'en', format = 'D MMM') => {
  if (locale === 'de' && format === 'D MMM') {
    const indexD = format.lastIndexOf('D')
    format = `${format.slice(0, indexD + 1)}o${format.slice(indexD + 1, format.length)}`
  }

  moment.locale(locale)
  return moment(date).format(format)
}
```

Because if I call the method with just 1 optional argument, it can be wrong:

```
renderDate('2019-09-04', 'Do MMM')
```

Now locale (the language) is a format, which is wrong.

What is the best approach to solve this issue? 
Should I pass an object and then check if the keys are present?

Then I could destructure, but I am not sure if this is the best approach:

```js
const renderDate = ({
  date,
  locale,
  format
}) => {
  if (locale === undefined) {
    locale = 'en'
  }
  if (format === undefined) {
    format = 'D MMM'
  }
  if (locale === 'de' && format === 'D MMM') {
    const indexD = format.lastIndexOf('D')
    format = `${format.slice(0, indexD + 1)}o${format.slice(indexD + 1, format.length)}`
  }

  moment.locale(locale)
  return moment(date).format(format)
}
console.log(renderDate('2019-09-04', 'Do MMM'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - an object is the only way to solve this if you can pass one, the other, or both of the two optional arguments. You can also use default values with this. And note that your `if` statement only runs if `format` is `D MMM`, so you can remove the `indexOf` and just use `0`:

```
export const renderDate = ({ date, locale = "en", format = "D MMM" } = {}) => {
  if (locale === "de" && format === "D MMM") {
    const indexD = 0;
    format = `${format.slice(0, indexD + 1)}o${format.slice(indexD + 1, format.length)}`;
  }
  moment.locale(locale);
  return moment(date).format(format);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just remove the format conditions, since I needed more flexibility